# Hive query execution with print off for profiling purpose

Tags: profiling, hive

I am testing the performance of a few queries in hive, thus printing the query result to the stdout or file should be avoided. In oracle sql plus, I could do

```
oracle> SET autotrace traceonly;
```

or

```
oracle> set autotrace on statistics;
```

Then

```
oracle> some query;
oracle> set autotrace trace off;
```

Is there equivalent statements in hive?

Answer (score 2):

You could just use the `--silent` or `-S` option of the Hive command-line utility to get rid of the Hive log message, but that will still print the output of your query on stdout. To avoid this, you can just redirect to `/dev/null`, so for example:

```
$ hive -S -e "SELECT * FROM mytable" > /dev/null
```

Comment: the `-S` would also stop printing hive status. I would avoid '-S' to still be able to keep track of the hive status. The redirect to `/dev/null` appeared to be what I needed, but I am wondering if there is any overhead. Comparing the choice of _print to stdout_, _redirect to file_, and _to /dev/null_, what are their additional (other than query itself) overhead.

Comment: @Causality `/dev/null` is like a regular file except it discards everything written to it, but it still functions as a regular file so there is no overhead. And comparing to printing to stdout, I think the impact is minimal since it's just a standard unix redirection. When you're dealing with unwanted output streams like here, using /dev/null is the way to go.

Comment: I updated the question. Basically the oracle sqlplus' `set autotrace` is what I want, as the db engine itself would disable print the query result, while the `>/dev/null` would still "print" results.

Comment: @Causality I don't know of any other way to make the output silent instead of using redirections, and after doing a bit of research there doesn't seem to be anything like it at least right now, but I may be wrong.